# How to set height to fill parent div dynamically with sticky header in mui-datatables

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, datatables, material-ui

This is my mui-datatables options:

```
  const options = {
    responsive: "standard",
    pagination: false,
    tableBodyHeight: '80vh',
  };

  return (
    <MUIDataTable
      title={"ACME Employee list"}
      data={data}
      columns={columns}
      options={options}
    />
  );
```

What I wanted to achieve was to get the Table's Body to automatically/dynamically expand to fill the remaining height in the parent's div. Note that I have `pagination: false`, so everything will be shown and scrollable while the header locks in place (sticky header).

See this image: [Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLEwy.png)

I have tried style the Table with `flexGrow: 1` but **I don't know where to put it.** The [mui-datatables docs](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables) **doesn't** have a list of children components in `<MUIDataTable />` unlike if I were using the original Material-UI Tables.

So now my current janky solution is to set `tableBodyHeight: '80vh'` which is terrible because at different breakpoints, the parent div height changes, and the table overflows.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add mui-datatables predefined prop called `tableBodyMaxHeight` and give css property `overflow-y: auto` to the tablebody

Comment: What do you mean by "predefined prop called `tableBodyMaxHeight"` ? 
It is an option that should be added to the `options` object, right? 
If you meant "add the `tableBodyMaxHeight` option", what value should I give it?

thx :D

Comment: Yes you are right. you have to add that in options and mention value in 'px' instead of giving it in 'vh'. once the table height(with rows) reaches the maxheight the scrollbar will appear by giving overflow-y: auto.